# Is there a bitcoin explorer that can visualize where the coins are flowing from one address into another?

Tags: chainanalysis

I remember playing with a bitcoin explorer tool awhile back where one can input a bitcoin address and see all the coins flowing into it in a tree like structure. I want to be able to investigate where the coins are flowing from and to. What is this tool?

Answer (score 1):

Every transaction on blockchain.com has a clickable "View Tree Chart" link, eg:
[3414e5f55d89959978575713446072b0d4b3e86b75be5e894b8614c6526d1218](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/3414e5f55d89959978575713446072b0d4b3e86b75be5e894b8614c6526d1218) -- this shows bitcoin addresses and even IP address that first broadcast the tx (if known).

Comment: but i can't click on orgin to see where those bitcoins came from.

Comment: @Patoshiパトシ You can click on the address and see all TX's there. The entire blockchain can be explored this way.

Comment: @JoseFonseca You cannot click on "ORIGIN" to see where those coins came from.

Comment: @Patoshiパトシ I clicked on the address and it shows every transaction ever: https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/19GXCEcG2UxJhVnnGx6ioffs2oFU39uoRa

Comment: @JoseFonseca I'm not talking about that. I'm talking about the tree view: http://prntscr.com/pk52q2 -- you cannot click on ORIGIN.

Comment: Looks like the link to the tree chart has dissapeared... or do i really need glasses?

Comment: Yes, the "Tree View" has been removed unfortunately. This seems to be the closest thing I can find now: [blockchain3d.info](https://blockchain3d.info)